# CNC engraving single line fonts

Tags: cnc

I want to engrave some letters from a 2D dxf file with single stroke fonts.

Is this easy to do in most CAM software?

I have not decided what CAM software to use yet, because the ability to do single stroke fonts is very important to me.

I have read on forums of different CAM software, that people often find this difficult. Maybe it is because single stroke fonts are not included in the software.

However I already have the font as a dxf, so all I am asking is for the machine to follow a single line, where the centre of the cutting tool follows the line.

Comment: What is your question, exactly? Whether it is "easy to do in most CAM software" or are you asking for a recommendation for a CAM software that can do this?

Comment: I want to know whether is is easy to do in most CAM software. If so then I can decide on what CAM software to use based on other requirements.

Comment: Well I didn't ever see such a sw. But I think .dxf if probably a vectorial output format, thus it is probably easy. I think your question is too broad, maybe you could narrow it to a specific software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is a simple operation.  The only real consideration is the shape/size of the cutter. Obviously a tapered cutter will carve a path where the width is proportional to the depth. Therefore some understanding of the toolpath and interference with other objects or cuts is necessary.

This is easily visualized and controlled by most CAM applications once the machine setup is understood. The DXF files may also need to be cleaned up if they were produced from a raster conversion.